# Проблемы с шифрованием php

Tags: php, криптография

Задача зашифровать куки и ( Если это необходимо и сессии ). Делал через статью, но что-то у меня не работает обратная дешифровка. Вот код того и другого в примере кук.
Шифровка:

```
        //Ключ шифрования
        $key = "qwe233jk312jx813893xk312";

        //Наименование кук шифровки
        $cook_login = "email";
        $cook_pass = "password";

        //Шифровка логина
        $vector_login = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $filter_cook_login = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, $key, $cook_login, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $vector_login);

        //Шифровка пароля
        $vector_pass = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $filter_cook_pass = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, $key, $cook_pass, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $vector_pass);
```

Далее дешифровка:

```
$cook_login = "email";
$cook_pass = "password";
$key = "qwe233jk312jx813893xk312";
$vector = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypt_name = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, $key, $cook_login, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $vector);
```

Вот со вторым проблема, выводиться это ( С обновлением стр меняется )...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете помочь? Не пойму в чем загвоздка:(

Answer (score 2):

mcrypt_create_iv() у вас создает разные IV для шифрования и расшифровки. А они должны совпадать.

Comment: Извините, что-то не дошло. Вы можете показать на примере моего кода, наглядно яснее...

Comment: Вот вы генерите случайный вектор для шифрования логина: $vector_login = mcrypt_create_iv()
А вот вы генерите ДРУГОЙ (как я и написал) вектор для его расшифровки:
$vector = mcrypt_create_iv()
А вектора для шифрования и расшифровки должны быть одинаковыми

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом. У меня в разных файлах они.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков нет, дело как раз в этом. IV и ключи шифрования должны совпадать при шифровании и расшифровке для симметричных алгоритмов.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо вектора, у вас еще и переменные перепутаны)
Третий параметр в **mcrypt_decrypt** должен быть **$filter_cook_login** а не исходная строка

```
//Ключ шифрования
$key = "qwe233jk312jx813893xk312";

//Наименование кук шифровки
$cook_login = "email";
$cook_pass = "password";

//Шифровка логина
$vector_login = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$filter_cook_login = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, $key, $cook_login, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $vector_login);
$decrypt_name = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_256, $key, $filter_cook_login, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $vector_login);

echo $decrypt_name;
```

По поводу примера, таблица для MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `password` CHAR(64) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `salt` CHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `reset_token` CHAR(75) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SHA256:timestamp' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Ну и PHP. Параметры вставляйте через bind, чтоб избежать SQLInjection

```
/**
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $salt
 *
 * @return string
 */
function calcHash($password, $salt) {
    return hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
}

/**
 * @param int $TTL Один день на подтверждение
 *
 * @return string
 */
function generateResetToken($TTL = 86400) {
    $randomToken = hash('sha256', (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128)));

    return $randomToken . ':' . (time() + $TTL);
}

/**
 * @param string $resetToken
 * @param string $newPassword Новый пароль
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
function resetPassword($resetToken, $newPassword) {
    list($token, $time) = explode(':', $resetToken);

    //Проверяем время жизни токена
    if ($time < time()) {
        return false;
    }

    $salt = generateSalt();
    $password = $newPassword;

    /* Устанавливаем пользователю новый пароль и соль, и сбрасываем токен
        UPDATE `user`
        SET
            `reset_token`= NULL,
            `password` = :password,
            `password` = :salt
        WHERE `reset_token` = :resetToken
    */

    return true;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
function generateSalt(){
    return md5(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
}

/**
 * @param string $email
 * @param string $password
 */
function signUp($email, $password) {
    $salt = generateSalt();
    $password = calcHash($password, $salt);

    //Вставить в базу(email является уникальным, поэтому IGNORE, либо проверяйте существование в транзакции)
    /*  INSERT IGNORE INTO `user` (
            `email`,
            `password`,
            `salt`
        ) VALUES (
            :email,
            :password,
            :salt
        );
    */
}
```

Comment: Вы не поняли, дешифратор находиться в другом файле и вывод происходит через куки.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно передавать вектор тоже через куки, либо писать его в базу или еще куда-то. Либо вообще не использовать его. Это не обязательный параметр.

Comment: Я просто только начал читать про шифровки кук и наткнулся на этот скрипт. Может у вас есть наилучший вариант? Чтобы я могу разобраться в правильном русле, или статьи.

Comment: @Ninazu не стоит IV хранить у юзера: по вектору можно проверить некоторые предположения относительно Г(П)СЧ хоста и даже получить его состояние на момент генерации IV.

Comment: Обычно в куках не хранят пароли. Начнём с этого. Только идентификатор сессии к примеру. Во вторых что это вам даёт? Куки легко можно украсть и в такой же зашифрованном виде отправить вам на сервер с другого компьютера

Comment: @Ninazu Понятно. А есть ли статейки как правильно хранить пароли?

Comment: Можно воспользоватся условно необратимыми алгоритмами вроде (md5, sha, ...) Только соль добавляйте, чтоб не прогоняли по таблицам.

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm